# How could the moon's mass increase?

Tags: doctor-who

The plot of *Kill The Moon* was rooted in the idea that

> the moon's gravity had increased, causing havoc on Earth and leading to a last-ditch space mission to blow the whole thing up.

It turned out that

> the increase in gravity was due to an increase in mass, itself caused by the growth of a spacefaring creature inside its egg. The moon *was* the egg, its true nature now revealed.

But

> animals don't just grow on their own; they consume materials. Mass can't appear out of nowhere — this is a fundamental physical law.

So where did all this material suddenly come from?

Comment: [Related](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/10/04/doctor_who_kill_the_moon_episode_7_review/)

Comment: The mass was quite possibly pulled straight out of a plot hole. It's hard to wrap your mind around the number of things that don't make sense. ("Without the moon we'll have no satellites and no internet." Seriously?)

Comment: You are trying to apply logic and common sense to Sci-Fi & Fantasy, so let me tell you: Abandon all hope ye who enter here.

Comment: @ThorstenS.: I don't see how that's different from any number of questions here. What's the site for, then?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I am just teasing. While there are many authors which are meticulous, very, *very* often you find in sci-fi & fantasy egregious offenders which are so senseless that you want to bang your head on the table. As Kerrek noted, you found a really serious offender.

Comment: I thought of this too. I was worried that there might be a bit of improbable physics in an episode of Doctor Who until I saw the answers here.

Comment: And in the end you see a moon-sized being flying away through space by flapping its wings. You don't even want to think about the power needed for a several thousand kilometre sized being to flap wings at a speed that humans can observe. And how does that help in vacuum anyway?

Comment: Moffat is the king of tossing science and physics out the window in favor of what he thinks is a good storyline.

Comment: @gnasher729: Yeah and a moon-sized egg popped out of it right after hatching. And hung there in orbit. Makes sense.

Comment: @gnasher729 It flies....*what* ??! I really thought the best offender is [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBizgLZX7W0) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There could be numerous hypothetical ways in which this could happen.

1) The answer by @SylvainL, although, as he mentions the amounot of energy that needs to be absorbed would be HUGE.

2) Absorbtion of mass. Asteroids and stuff, although this option is also very unlikely.

3) Some kind of 'umbilical cord' to another dimension/space-time position which feeds the creature (See [Wormhole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole)).

4) Some quantum process which converts virtual particles into real particles. This means that somehow the creature manages to extract real particles from vacuum (See for example [Hawking radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation)).

This is a sci-fi show, so I'm pretty sure anyone could imagine some way to explain it and then try to adjust it as much as possible to our current scientific knowledge.

Comment: Heh, I quite like #3

Comment: It would've been nice if the episode at least gave a glimmer of a hint about the method, though. Or even just lampshade it: a quick throwaway line from one of the characters, something to the effect of "well, that breaks all known laws of physics, but since it's happening, it's demonstrably possible, so let's move on."

Answer (score 5):

Well, if it's a living that is spacefaring, then there is the possibility that this creature can directly absorb some kind of space energy and convert it into mass; following the well known Einsten's equation.

Of course, the quantity of absorbed energy necessary to do that should be enormous but hey, in space, you don't have to pay for it.